# How do I create a custom authorization policy in asp.net core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

my asp.net core 2.0 api has an endpoint with this route pattern:
/clients/{clientid}/orders

My JWT Token include a claim (Claimtype = 'ClientId').

I want to ensure the client id specified in the url, matches the client id specified in claim set.

I know i can check for the existence of the ClientId claim like this:

```
 cfg.AddPolicy("AuthorizedClient", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireAssertion(
                context => context.User.HasClaim(claim =>
                               claim.Type == "ClientId"...
```

but I haven't found any documentation or example that demonstrates authorizing using the context of the incoming request action parameters.

Comment: Why would you need request action parameters?

Comment: so the presence of the ClientId claim is not enough.  The claim value must match that of the ClientId parameter in the request url.

Comment: Well you can call `context.GetRouteData()` to get the route data if that's sufficient. It's an extension method, so you may also need to include `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;`

Comment: the context is an instance of AuthorizationHandlerContext which doesn't have access to the GetRouteData().   If I'm misinterpreting your response, perhaps you could include a code snippet.   Thanks.